# The string builder I created for the DNA sequence stops every time at the first occurrence of "CCTGG"

Tags: java

The string builder I created for the DNA sequence stops every time at the
first occurrence of "CCTGG" and replaces it with "|CCTGG". I need it to go through the whole DNA sequence and replace every occurrence of "CCTGG" with "|CCTGG", as well as give me the position of the first character.

```
 import java.io.File;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
* Write a description of class DNA here.
* 
*
*/
public class DNA
{
  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    long EcoRI = 0;
    long EcoRII = 0;
    long HindIII=0;
    long SmaI=0;
    int line;

    File seq = new File("Sequence.txt");
    Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(seq);
    StringBuilder sequenceC = new StringBuilder();
    String sequenceS;

    while(fileReader.hasNextLine()){
        String lines = fileReader.nextLine();

        String lines1 = lines.replaceAll("\\s+",""); 
        String lines2 = lines1.replaceAll("\\d","");

        String[] sequenceR = lines2.split("\n");

        for(int i = 0; i<sequenceR.length; i++){
            sequenceC.append(sequenceR[i]+"\n");

            if(sequenceR[i].contains("GAATTC")){
                EcoRI +=1;
                String match = "GAATTC";
                int position =  sequenceC.indexOf(match);
                int previous = position;
                sequenceC.replace(position,(position+6), " G|AATTC ");

                System.out.println("A ECORI enzyme restrictor was found "       + (position) +
                "characters in on the DNA sequence");
                System.out.println();

            }


            else if(sequenceR[i].contains("CCTGG")){
                EcoRII +=1;

                String match = "CCTGG";
                int position =  sequenceC.indexOf(match);


                sequenceC.replace(position,(position+5), " |CCTGG ");

                 System.out.println("A ECORII enzyme restrictor was found " + (position-1) +
                " characters in on the DNA sequence");
                System.out.println();

            }


            else if(sequenceR[i].contains("AAGCTT")){
                HindIII +=1;
                String match = "AAGCTT";
                int position =  sequenceC.indexOf(match);
                sequenceC.replace(position,(position+6),  " A|AGCTT ");

                 System.out.println("A cut for HINDIII enzyme restrictor was found " + (position+1) +
                " characters in on the DNA sequence");
                System.out.println();

            }


            else if(sequenceR[i].contains(" CCCGGG ")){
                SmaI+=1;
                String match = "CCCGGG";
                int position =  sequenceC.indexOf(match);
                sequenceC.replace(position,(position+6), "CCC|GGG");

                 System.out.println("A SMAI enzyme restrictor was found " + position +
                " characters in on the DNA sequence");
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
    }




    System.out.println("EcoRI: " + EcoRI);
    System.out.println("EcoRII: " + EcoRII);
    System.out.println("HindIII: " + HindIII);
    System.out.println("SmaI: " + SmaI);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println(sequenceC);
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: use the string.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) method to replace all the occurrences at once and string.split(String regex).length-1 to determine how many occurrences there are. if you want the position of the sequnces I would use an extra for loop to do this.

Comment: Sorry I just saw your comment. I finished it yesterday! Used separate while loops for the information contained within the if statements to get all occurrence of each match. Also used the same while loops to replace the matches with the correct encoding sequence within the StringBuilder i created. Thanks for the input though!